# Can we use generic exception in throws?

Tags: java, exception, throws

I have a silly doubt. While using `throws` I know we specify multiple exceptions. My query is can we include `Exception` (generic) also along with other specific exceptions? Is that right coding approach?

```
public String display() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, Exception {
    ...
}
```

Here using `Exception` is right approach??

Comment: If the exception is not happening in the code then why `throws` the exception.

Comment: 1. If you declare that your method throws a checked exception (something that extends `Exception` rather than `RuntimeException`), your force the caller to handle it. They need to write the try-catch even if they might not need one, which I would say is a bit silly (I really don't want to go into debate whether checked exceptions are bad or not). 2. If you force the caller to handle it, but it is the most generic exception possible - what do you want them to handle?

Comment: I really wanted the caller to handle whatever the method throws! only point is apart from specific exceptions if i also throw generic exception what is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

It is legal code.

It is a bad idea.

The reason that it is a bad idea is that the caller now has to handle (or propagate) `Exception`.  But an `Exception` could be almost anything.  How can you do anything sensible<sup>1</sup> with an exception in an exception handler if you don't know what it could be?

I would argue that if you don't know what the cause of an exception is, the only *totally* safe thing you can do is to log it and terminate the application.  In some contexts you could try to log the exception, "fail" the request and carry on with the next one.  That may be a sensible strategy,  if service availability is the highest priority, and the system is designed to be robust (e.g. idempotent requests, transactional implementation).  However, there is a risk that this approach will increase the damage.  But the problem with throwing `Exception` is that you make it much harder to discriminate between errors that are recoverable and those that are not.

Comment: Wow! That explains!! got the point why Sonar keeps telling me to remove generic exception!

Comment: one more silly doubt! considering am not including the generic "Exception" in throws? Will it be right approach to catch the Exception inside the method.
I understand I ask naive questions. Since it never throws compiler error, I wanted to adhere to coding standards for better code quality!

Comment: Go to the Documentation example page I linked to and look at the other examples in the same topic.   There is one that talks about catching `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

It is legal Java code.

First part for the usage of `Exception` in `throws` declaration.

It should seldom be written in production code, before it suggests that the method could throw absolutely any checked exception, which is quite uncommon.

But it is currently used in Junit tests. The aim of a test function is to test one single feature, and should be as simple as possible because it is expected to not contain logic errors. So it is common to write the test as:

```
@Test
public void testFeature() throws Exception {
    //actual test that can call any function declaring checked exception
}
```

Here this just means that you do not want to worry for possible exception declared in functions used in the test body.

---

But your code declares Exception *in addition to* other exception (sub-)classes. That is useless because all exception classes are subclasses of `Exception`, thus `IOException` and `FileNotFoundException` **are** `Exception`s.

So even if legal, this does not make sense: if you put `Exception` in `throws` declaration, you should remove all other exception classes because they are already contained in the `Exception` declaration.

Comment: fine! but sonar  throws an error when we throw generic exception even though if i had included the other specific exceptions!

Comment: @BalachandarThangavel: Looks like I had only answered half of the question... See my edit.

Comment: Got it! i have removed the exception from throws and the sonar is happy :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion method can throw generic Exception, when you business logic and your pipeline works like application has to continue work even after fatal error, log this error as FFDC and continue works. If your application has to shutdown after fatal eror, then your method has not to throw generic Exception.